# char array assignment

Tags: c, arrays, file-handling

i am trying to read lines from a text file into char array, but there is something wrong. Please see the code and let me know what am i doing wrong.
thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    int i=0,j;
    char* string[100];
    char line[100];
    FILE *file; 
    file = fopen("patt", "r"); 
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL) {
        printf("%d %s",i, line);
        string[i]=line;
        i++;
    }
    for (j=0 ; j<i ; j++) {
        printf("string[%d] %s",j, string[j]);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

the input file patt has the following contents.

```
rec
cent
ece
ce
recent
nt
```

On executing the codes above i get this

```
0 rec
1 cent
2 ece
3 ce
4 recent
5 nt
string[0] nt
string[1] nt
string[2] nt
string[3] nt
string[4] nt
string[5] nt
```

what i expect is this

```
0 rec
1 cent
2 ece
3 ce
4 recent
5 nt
string[0] rec
string[1] cent
string[2] ece
string[3] ce
string[4] recent
string[5] nt
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3):

You are repeatedly writing to the same array.

`while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL) {`

In this line you repeatedly, write to the array `line`.

---

I think you are misunderstanding what `char* string[100];` does. You are using it as an array of arrays, while it actually is an array of 100 pointers.

To correct the problem, you need to first allocate a new memory block in every iteration :

```
 string[i] = malloc(strlen(line)+1);
```

Then you need to copy the contents of `line` to `string[i]` :

```
strcpy(string[i], line);
```

Also, at the end of the program you will need to use `free` to release the memory.

Comment: what is correct way to assign those lines read from file to the string array

Comment: thanks a lot, it works now
PS: could you suggest better way to this char* string[100]; char line[100];

Comment: 1) Don't cast the return from `malloc` (doing so can hide a bug). 2) You haven't allocated enough space for the NUL terminator on the string -- you need ` malloc(strlen(line) + 1)`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Whats the reasoning for not casting the pointer returned from malloc ? I have seen a few posts on SO saying the same, but no explanation.

Comment: @AshRj: the cast will stop the compiler for complaining even though you haven't included the proper prototype for `malloc` with `#include <stdlib.h>` -- but without the prototype, you can get incorrect behavior (the compiler assumes it returns an `int`, then casts that to a pointer, rather than knowing it returns a pointer). If/when `int` and `void *` are different sizes (e.g., 64-bit code on some compilers) this won't work correctly.

Comment: @AshRj You should have stumbled over [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169) which really does try to provide some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your `string[i]=line;` means you're repeatedly storing a pointer to the same buffer (`line`) into each successive item in `string`. Something like this:

[image]

To make things work, you need to allocate a new buffer for each of those to point at, something like: `string[i] = dupe_string(line);`, where `dupe_string` will be something like:

```
char *dupe_string(char const *in) { 
    char *dupe;
    if (NULL != (dupe = malloc(strlen(in) + 1)))
        strcpy(dupe, in);
    return dupe;
}
```

Note that since this uses `malloc` to allocate space for each string, you'll eventually need to call `free` for each of those to avoid having a memory leak.

Comment: thanks, do you mean I have to use something like for(i=0 to 100) and then free(string[i])

Comment: i tried to implement this on what Ashrj suggested but there are errors like these -> test.c:23:8: error: conflicting types for ‘dupe_string’
test.c:12:16: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘dupe_string’ was here
test.c: In function ‘dupe_string’:
test.c:26:11: error: ‘dup’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:26:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: @user1733911: Yes, except that you want to ensure you only free as many strings as you allocated (calling `free` on whatever random value an uninitialized pointer might contain will give undefined behavior). Alternatively, you can initialize the un-used pointers to `NULL`. As for the others: I had a typo in the code --`dup` should have been `dupe`. You can either put `dupe_string` *before* the code that uses it, or else add a prototype like `char *dupe_string(char const *);` before the function that calls it.

Answer (score 1):

To help you out understanding your code:

- You are writing to `string[i]` the address of the `line` every time, while the content of the array `line` keeps changing throughout the loop.
  This results in, all `string[i]` to contain the address of the same variable i.e. `line`.
  At the end of the loop, the last line read from the file is stored in `line` array. Now while you are printing string[i], you are printing the data present in the variable `line`.Since, all the instance of string[i] contain the same address of `line`, they all are printing the same value i.e. `nt` in your output.

> ```
> int main(void) {
>     int i=0,j;
>     char* string[100];
>     char line[100];
>     FILE *file; 
>     file = fopen("patt", "r"); 
>     while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)!=NULL) {//You missed the ()'s in the sizeof
>         printf("%d %s",i, line);
>         string[i]=line;
>         i++;
>     }
> ```

*What you should have instead done is:

```
int main(void) {
int i=0,j;
char* string[100];
char line[100];
FILE *file; 
file = fopen("patt", "r"); 
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)!=NULL) {//You missed the ()'s in the sizeof
    printf("%d %s",i, line);
    string[i]=malloc(strlen(line)+1); ///You need to allocate some memory to char* string[i] here
    if(string[i] == NULL)//Do a NULL check if malloc failed
      //Handle NULL here
    strncpy(string[i],line,strlen(line)+1);//Use strncpy to copy line into the malloced memory in string[i]
    i++;
}
```

Now, since you have malloced the memory for storing you data you need to free the memory too.
So, instead of this in your code:

```
    for (j=0 ; j<i ; j++) {
        printf("string[%d] %s",j, string[j]);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Do this:

```
    for (j=0 ; j<i ; j++) {
    printf("string[%d] %s",j, string[j]);
    free(string[j]);
    }
   fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```

Now, that should give you what you wanted.

Comment: Your code doesn't include NUL terminators when it creates the duplicate strings, so when he tries to print them out, he'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: yes i got hell lot of crazy errors

Comment: It was a typo and so was `free(string[i]);`.

Comment: The code is fixed now. Note that you can store max. 100 lines due to `char* string[100];` in your code. You can use `realloc()` instead of using a static array for reading as many lines as needed, from the file.

Comment: @askmish: I think "fixed" it a bit strong of a word. You've managed to make the zigs and zags match up correctly so you no longer have undefined behavior, but code like: `strncpy(string[i],line,strlen(line)+1);` is...horrible. In fact, anytime you even consider using `strncpy`, stop, take a deep breath, and think. If `strncpy` is the right answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question.